# Low accuracy of trained model when dataset contains 10^5 observations and 128 features using "Statistic and machine learning toolbox" of Matlab

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

The entrys are real numbers (each row is a channel output, where blocklength n= 128).
The accuracy is approx. 50%. The labels contain elements of the set {0,1}. The dataset is balanced.

For smaller blocklength (n= 32 and 50000 observations) the accuracy is approx. 90%. In this case, fine and cosine KNN perform the best.

For the case where n = 128,
feature selection does not increase the accuracy. I have tried several samples.
Is there any hope to get a better accuracy?
Is the value range a problem? I assume that a bigger sample size would help but it would lead to high computational complexity.

I used the proposed Matlabcode to select featuers:
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%savedata is a 10^5 x 128 matrix, savedata_m is a  10^5 x1 vector with % entries of 0's and 1's.

rng(1); % For reproducibility

```
cvp = cvpartition(savedata_m,'holdout',20000);

Xtrain = savedata(cvp.training,:);
ytrain = savedata_m(cvp.training,:);
Xtest  = savedata(cvp.test,:);
ytest  = savedata_m(cvp.test,:);

nca = fscnca(Xtrain,ytrain,'FitMethod','none');

L = loss(nca,Xtest,ytest)

nca = fscnca(Xtrain,ytrain,'FitMethod','exact','Lambda',0,...
      'Solver','sgd','Standardize',true);

L = loss(nca,Xtest,ytest)

cvp = cvpartition(ytrain,'kfold',5);

numvalidsets = cvp.NumTestSets;

n = length(ytrain);

lambdavals = linspace(0,20,20)/n;

lossvals = zeros(length(lambdavals),numvalidsets);

for i = 1:length(lambdavals)

    for k = 1:numvalidsets

        Xt = Xtrain(cvp.training(k),:);
        yt = ytrain(cvp.training(k),:);
        Xvalid = Xtrain(cvp.test(k),:);
        yvalid = ytrain(cvp.test(k),:);

        nca = fscnca(Xt,yt,'FitMethod','exact', ...
             'Solver','sgd','Lambda',lambdavals(i), ...
             'IterationLimit',30,'GradientTolerance',1e-4, ...
             'Standardize',true);
                  
        lossvals(i,k) = loss(nca,Xvalid,yvalid,'LossFunction','classiferror');
    end
end

meanloss = mean(lossvals,2);
figure()
plot(lambdavals,meanloss,'ro-')
xlabel('Lambda')
ylabel('Loss (MSE)')
grid on

[~,idx] = min(meanloss);

bestlambda = lambdavals(idx) % Find the best lambda value

bestloss = meanloss(idx)

%Fit the nca model on all data using best lambda and plot the feature weights

nca = fscnca(Xtrain,ytrain,'FitMethod','exact','Solver','sgd',...
    'Lambda',bestlambda,'Standardize',true,'Verbose',1);

figure()
plot(nca.FeatureWeights,'ro')
xlabel('Feature index')
ylabel('Feature weight')
grid on

%tol    = 0.5;
tol    = 0.0001;
selidx = find(nca.FeatureWeights > tol*max(1,max(nca.FeatureWeights)))

L = loss(nca,Xtest,ytest)

%Classify observations using the selected features

features = Xtrain(:,selidx);

classificationKNN = fitcknn(...
    features, ...
    ytrain, ...
    'Distance', 'Euclidean', ...
    'Exponent', [], ...
    'NumNeighbors', 1, ...
    'DistanceWeight', 'Equal', ...
    'Standardize', true, ...
    'ClassNames', [1; 2]);

L = loss(classificationKNN,Xtest(:,selidx),ytest)
%--------------------------------------------------------------_
```

---

Furthermore, I used sequencial feature selection.
Code:

```
c = cvpartition(savedata_m,'k',10);
opts = statset('Display','iter');
 %Model= fitcecoc(XT,yT,'Learners','knn')
fun = @(XT,yT,Xt,yt)loss(fitcecoc(XT,yT,'Learners','knn'),Xt,yt);

[fs,history] = sequentialfs(fun,savedata,savedata_m,'cv',c,'options',opts)
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I get the following.

> > sequencialFeatureSelection
> > Start forward sequential feature selection:
> > Initial columns included:  none
> > Columns that can not be included:  none
> > Step 1, added column 15, criterion value 9.8064e-05
> > Final columns included:  15

fs =

1×128 logical array

Columns 1 through 42

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Columns 43 through 84

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Columns 85 through 126

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Columns 127 through 128

0   0

history =

struct with fields:

```
  In: [1×128 logical]
Crit: 9.8064e-05
```

Comment: Your question needs a lot of clarification. However, I understand that your problem is accuracy of the model. Some hints are - check if your dataset if balanced, Find out important features and also remove unnecessary correlated features. Make sure you are feeding the right data to the classifier and not feeding it in pieces

Comment: Thanks a lot. The dataset is balanced and I apllied feature selection.